# Is it possible to mediate Interstitial ads using AdMob?

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I have set up an AdMob mediation in my android app, it's working fine, but I also want AdMob to mediate interstitial ads from the other providers. I was unable to find any help or documentation on that, so I am asking here.

This is the code I have for the banner mediation:

```
    MMSDK.initialize(this);
    millennialExtras = new MillennialAdapterExtras();

    inmobiExtras = new InMobiAdapterExtras();

    mopubExtras = new MoPubExtras();

    FlurryAgent.init(this, "some id");
    flurryExtras = new FlurryAdapterExtras();

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addNetworkExtras(millennialExtras)
            .addNetworkExtras(inmobiExtras)
            .addNetworkExtras(mopubExtras)
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And then the ads start rolling.

Now for the interstitials, I am trying to do it like this:
in onCreate I have this:

```
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("some id");
    adRequestInterstitial = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addNetworkExtras(millennialExtras)
            .addNetworkExtras(inmobiExtras)
            .addNetworkExtras(mopubExtras)
            .build();
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestInterstitial);
```

and then I have this button for showing interstitial:

```
public void showInterstitial(View v) {
        interstitialAd.show();
}
```

My problem is, that I don't know if this is the proper way to do it. I use the same adapter objects for both the AdMob banner and the AdMob interstitial. I have added the needed networks and ad spaces in AdMob dashboard for the interstitial ad space.

So is this way correct?

Comment: This page has instructions for many ad networks: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/mediation-networks

Comment: there aren't any instructions how to mediate interstitial ads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely mediate interstitials for other ad networks using Admob mediation. And the way that you have done it is exactly correct.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. For Interstitial ads mediation i have added the SDK and Adapters of network but Interstitial ads are not receiving. I am following this link- https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/mediation